# Conditional cumulative summing with group_by in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, cumulative-sum

So I've got an ID an event, and I want to use group_by (or some similar function) to do a conditional cumulative sum.  Here's the data:

```
ID  Event
42  NA
42  1
42  2
42  NA
42  1
43  NA
43  1
43  2
43  2
```

and what I want to do is have two new columns that count the 1s and the 2s, cumulatively, without collapsing any of the data:

```
ID  Event   count_1s    count_2s
42  NA      0           0
42  1       1           0
42  2       1           1
42  NA      1           1
42  1       2           1
43  NA      0           0
43  1       1           0
43  2       1           1
43  2       1           2
```

So I understand how to use group_by to sum them all up by ID, something like this:

```
t <- data %>% group_by(ID, Event) %>% summarize(count_1s = sum(!is.na(Event == 1)))
```

But what I can't understand is how to get a running conditional sum -- seems like group_by will collapse my data and I need to maintain every row.

EDIT: so the accepted answer works perfectly, but just one more question.  What if the values are different, by event?  For example:

```
ID  Event   count_a count_b
42  NA      0           0
42  1       1           0
42  2       1           1
42  NA      1           1
42  1       2           1
43  NA      0           0
43  3       1           0
43  4       1           1
43  4       1           2
```

There will always only be two Event values per ID, (doesn't matter which is a and which is b) and I want them to reset each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After grouping by the 'ID' column, we can create the 'count_1s' by comparing the elements in 'Event' that is equal to 1 and is not an `NA`, then `cumsum` the logical index.  In a similar way, we can create the 'count_2s'.

```
 library(dplyr)
 data %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(count_1s= cumsum(Event==1 & !is.na(Event)),
           count_2s= cumsum(Event==2 & !is.na(Event)))
#     ID Event count_1s count_2s
#  (int) (int)    (int)    (int)
#1    42    NA        0        0
#2    42     1        1        0
#3    42     2        1        1
#4    42    NA        1        1
#5    42     1        2        1
#6    43    NA        0        0
#7    43     1        1        0
#8    43     2        1        1
#9    43     2        1        2
```

#### Update

Using the OP's updated dataset, after we group by 'ID', we can create a new column 'Event1', by converting the 'Event' to `factor` class and then coerce it back to `numeric` class (or another option is `match`ing the 'Event' with `unique` elements of 'Event'), and then create the 'count_a', and 'count_b' as before.

```
data2 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(Event1= as.numeric(factor(Event, levels=unique(Event))), 
          count_a= cumsum(Event1==1 & !is.na(Event1)), 
          count_b= cumsum(Event1==2 & !is.na(Event1))) %>%
   select(-Event1)
#    ID Event count_a count_b
#  (int) (int)   (int)   (int)
#1    42    NA       0       0
#2    42     1       1       0
#3    42     2       1       1
#4    42    NA       1       1
#5    42     1       2       1
#6    43    NA       0       0
#7    43     3       1       0
#8    43     4       1       1
#9    43     4       1       2
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L), Event = c(NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Event"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

data2 <- structure(list(ID = c(42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L), Event = c(NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Event"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun -- I updated the question, any idea on how to make that count?

Comment: @skathan What is `count_a` and `count_b`?

Comment: So basically, I want to do the exact same thing as before, but I can't say "Event==1" and "Event==2" because the numbers change by each ID.  So ID 42 would have events 1 and 2, ID 43 might have events 6 and 7, ID 8 might have events 14 and 37.  Each ID only has 2 events that appear a certain number of times, but they are two different values each time.

Comment: You can convert to `factor` for that.

Comment: how does one convert to factor?

Comment: @skathan Updated my post.